# browser redirect to my page in PHP

Tags: php, browser

when I search on browser for any page (may be goolge.com, facebook.com ) it should redirect to my page.
is it possible in PHP ?

is there any settings in web browsers?

Comment: what are you trying to make here? sounds not right. Anyhow one way of redirecting is by putting a dns entry or changing host file

Comment: @ris :  yes   it should work for every URL

Comment: I am creating an application, logged user can search and use internet  If user is not logged   it should redirect to my page

Comment: Logged user can search and use the internet? But they will get redirected to your page? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using the internet?

Comment: are talking about searching within your application ??

Comment: @Rashid: I think you already know this header('Location: '.$newURL);

Comment: @ sajad : I am not opened my php file        if user open browser and search somthing  ,  if he not a logged user, then go to my php page

Answer (score 0):

There are no settings that will do that in your browser. 
But there are tehcniques that you would like to test.

- Hosts file editing on windows to redirect URL
- Install a google chrome extension to redirect URL

Comment: if i edit in host file  like this ' 0.0.0.0    www.facebook.com'   it will not load Facebook only            I want to block all pages

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it can be done in PHP, it's lower level at the networking level not the application level.

Have a look at

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/